# How to format SQL query without using string +

Tags: c#

I am currently formatting my SQL queries like this in C#:

```
  string query = "SELECT * "+
                   "FROM product p"+
                   "JOIN order o ON p.productID = o.productID";
```

Is there any alternative ways to achieve the above format without using the + sign?

Comment: Put it in a resource file ... use stored procedures ... use an ORM ...

Comment: I use ORM for large projects.

Comment: @ta.speot.is why would you intentionally make it harder to maintain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the  @ symbol:

```
string query= @"SELECT *  
                  FROM product p 
                  JOIN order   o ON p.productID = o.productID";
```